# HTML not linking to CSS if they're on different folders

Tags: html, css, jsp, hyperlink, path

I have a problem with my CSS file. I'm testing a stylesheet but I can't seem to be able to link it to HTML unless they're on the same folder. Here's my package structure

[image: Package structure]
.

index.jsp is in WebContent and styles.css in WEB-INF/css/styles.css relative to index.jsp. This is how  I'm trying to link the file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/css/styles.css">
```

But this does nothing. However, when I put styles.css in the same folder as index.jsp and change this line to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

it works just fine. I know my path is correct in the original case because I can ctrl+click to open the css file from the jsp file in Eclipse, so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, just tried and isn't working. It is in WebContent, and I'm sure of that because I can ctrl+click to open the css file from the jsp so my path should be fine

Comment: What do you mean include? I don't need that folder for this case

Comment: It does have permissions. Funny thing, I just discovered that if I put the css folder (the one which contains the css file) directly under WebContent and use this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"> it works too. I honestly have no idea what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WEB-INF` folder is **by definition** not accessible via HTTP request; if you want to serve any content from the `WEB-INF` folder, it has to be done using Servlet/JSP.

Solution: put your CSS file(s) outside the `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Ok, that explains what was happening to me. Thank you very much Pete and Jozef for the help!